# Node res.write() and fs.readFile

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

all. 
Is there some way to dynamically add `res.write()`? For example, the video tag source is from ‘/show1’, ‘/show2’ to ‘/show3’. I want to show all these three videos on the page, so i put res.write in a for loop.

```
  var current =3;
    for(var i=1; i<= current; i++){
            console.log("I am in a loop" +'/show' + i);
            res.write("<video src='" + '/show'+ i + "' / autoplay>");
        }
```

It didn' work, the screen shows a black box.

When I want to dynamically add some tag in js, what i am usually doing is below, but with res.write, i don't know how to do like this:

```
for(var m =0; m< data.length; m++){
         document.getElementById('messages2').innerHTML += data[m] + "," + "<br/>";
    }
```

Or `fs.readFile` is a better way do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with calling `write` multiple times. Here's the [doc](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding) on it:

> This sends a chunk of the response body. This method **may be called multiple times** to provide successive parts of the body.

(Emphasis added.)

Your `write` is not outputting correct HTML. I suggest something like:

```
res.write("<video src='/show"+ i + "' autoplay />");
```

In the code in the question the forward slash appeared between the `src` attribute and `autoplay`. This is definitely wrong. If I look at what your code would produce in Firefox, Firefox reports an error due to the location of the slash.

Answer (score 1):

Build the markup dynamically, and output it at the end

```
var current = 3,
    markup  = '';

for(var i=1; i <= current; i++){
     markup += "<video src='" + '/show'+ i + "' / autoplay></video>");
}

res.send(markup);
```

Comment: Thank you!!Is res.send or res.write? I've tried, And this solution make one video tag embedded with other video tag.

Comment: @user2592038 - that's because the video tag isn't closed. Edited the answer.